# groupby an element with jq

Tags: jq

I have the following json:

```
{"us":{"$event":"5bbf4a4f43d8950b5b0cc6d2"},"org":"TΙ UIH","rc":{"$event":"13"}}
{"us":{"$event":"5bbf4a4f43d8950b5b0cc6d3"},"org":"TΙ UIH","rc":{"$event":"13"}}
{"us":{"$event":"5bbf4a4f43d8950b5b0cc6d4"},"org":"AB KIO","rc":{"$event":"13"}}
{"us":{"$event":"5bbf4a4f43d8950b5b0cc6d5"},"org":"GH SVS","rc":{"$event":"17"}}
```

How could i achieve the following output result? (tsv)

```
13 TΙ UIH 2
13 AB KIO 1
17 GH SVS 1
```

so far from what i have searched,

```
jq -sr 'group_by(.org)|.[]|[.[0].org, length]|@tsv'
```

how could i add one more group_by to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to obtain the expected result from your sample JSON using the following :

```
group_by(.org, .rc."$event")[] | [.[0].rc."$event", .[0].org, length] | @tsv
```

You can [try it on jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/FPBiC8xt3p).

The modification of the `group_by` clause ensures we will have one entry by pair of `.org`/`.rc.$event` (without it we would only have one entry by `.org`, which might hide some `.rc.$event`).

Then we add the `.rc.$event` to the array you create just as you did with the `.org`, accessing the value of the first item of the array since we know they're all the same anyway.

To sort the result, you can put it in an array and use `sort_by(.[0])` which will sort by the first element of the rows :

```
[group_by(.org, .rc."$event")[] | [.[0].rc."$event", .[0].org, length]] | sort_by(.[0])[] | @tsv
```

Comment: thank you, could i also somehow sort values by $event value?

Comment: @meno I've updated the answer to specify a sort order. Note that you can specify more than one, e.g. `sort_by(.[0], .[2])` to sort values with the same $event by record count